# Example 2.3.5; Functional Analysis book by S. Kesavan

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The author in this example is trying to show that the norm of Hilbert matrix is less than or equal to $\pi$. Hilbert matrix has entries
$$a_{ij}=\frac{1}{i+j+1};1\leq i,j \leq \infty$$ He used the fact that if $\exists$ a sequence of positive real numbers $({p_{i}})$ with $\beta >0$ and $\gamma >0$  satisfying $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}p_{i}\leq\beta p_{j};\:\forall j\in\mathbb{N}$$
and
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}p_{j}\leq\gamma p_{i};\:\forall i\in\mathbb{N}$$
Then $A\in L(l_{2})$ and $||A||^{2}\leq \beta\gamma$.

For Hilbert matrix he considered,
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{ij}p_{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(i+1/2+j+1/2)\sqrt{i+1/2}}$$
$$<\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+j+1/2)\sqrt{x}}$$
$$=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t^{2}+j+1/2}$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{j+1/2}}$$
*I am not able to understand the second step of the proof that how he is able to relate summation with integration.*

Comment: The sum is even less than $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1+j}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the sums starting from $i=0$ is a mistake. They should start from $i=1$. Now $\int_{i-1+\frac 1 2}^{i+\frac 1 2} \frac 1 {(x+j+\frac 1 2)\sqrt x } dx > \frac 1 {(i+\frac 1 2 +j+\frac 1 2) \sqrt {i+\frac  1 2}}$. Summing over $i$ from $1$ to $\infty$ gives the inequality.

Comment: I have checked the book once again and the summation is from $i=0$ onward. But clearly deriving the fact doesn't require summation from $i=0$. So, you have used the fact that $$\frac{1}{(x+j+1/2)\sqrt{x}} \geq \frac{1}{(i+1/2+j+1/2)\sqrt{i+1/2}} $$ when $ i-1+1/2 \leq x \leq i+1/2 $.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav $a_{ij}$ is not even defined when $i=0$.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to make an extended comment on the remark in the OP "I am not able to understand the second step of the proof that how he is able to relate summation with integration."

I had the same difficulty, and resolved it by carefully looking at the replacement of the sum by an integral.

The sum in question is

$$s(j) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a(i,j)\tag{1}$$

where the summand is

$$a(i,j)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{i+\frac{1}{2}} (i+j+1)}\tag{2}$$

A  modified summand which will become an integrand subsequently is

$$b(x,j) = a(i\to x-\frac{1}{2},j)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(x+j+\frac{1}{2})}\tag{3}$$

Now consider the graph

[image]

The trick is to look at the half integer points. Because the second derivative $\frac{\partial^2 b(x,j)}{\partial x^2} >0$ the integral between consecutive integer points is greater than the area of the corresponding rectangular strip. To make this evident, compare the areas under the blue curve and those under the yellow curve in the intervals from $i=1$ to $i=\frac{3}{2}$ with that in the interval from $i=\frac{3}{2}$ to $i=2$. We see that the area of "triangle" in the first interval is slightly gerater than that of the second "triangle":

Hence follows the inequality.

The integral is then calculated from the formula

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(x+j+a)} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a+j}}\tag{4}$$

**Discussion**

Because in our case we have $a=\frac{1}{2}$ we find

$$s(j) < \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+j}}\tag{5}$$

but numerical evidence shows that even

$$s(j) < \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1+j}}\tag{6}$$

I was not able to find a proof of the stronger inequality $(6)$. So it remains as an interesting open problem.

We can also easily find a lower bound of $s(j)$ by just integrating

$$s(j) > \int_0^{\infty } a(x,j) \, dx = \frac{2 \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{j+1}}\right)}{\sqrt{j+\frac{1}{2}}}\tag{7}$$

Comment: Your answer is really insightful. Even when I first encountered this problem I tried to relate it with area under the graph. About your claim, what sort of numerical evidence are you talking about.

Comment: @ Himanshu Yadav Thank you. To be honest, I have never used the half-integer argument before, and notice that it only works here because the integral over the diverging $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is finite. "Numerical evidence" means just calculating the sum numerically and comparing it to the explicit expressions $(6)$.

Answer (score 0):

The summation considers only positive integer values for $i$, while the integral considers all positive real values of $i$.  Since all the other terms in the summation are positive, it follows that the summation can be no bigger than the integral.

Consider, just to make it easier to see, the first three terms:
$$\sum_{i=0}^2 \frac{1}{(i+1/2+j+1/2)\sqrt{i+1/2}} = \frac{1}{(1+j)\sqrt{3/2}} + \frac{1}{(2+j)\sqrt{5/2}} + \frac{1}{(3+j)\sqrt{7/2}} $$
Then an upper-bounding integral for this is:
$$\int_0^3 \frac{dx}{(x+j+1/2)\sqrt{x}} \geq \frac{1}{(j+1)\sqrt{1/2}} + \frac{1}{(j+2)\sqrt{3/2}} + \frac{1}{(j+3)\sqrt{5/2} } $$
where we've established the inequality by taking just three points from the domain of integration ($x=1/2,\ 3/2$ and $5/2$).  Since each term of this can be directly compared with the sum, and each term from the integral is larger, the inequality follows, as adding the in the rest of the domain of integration can only increase the value.

Comment: Thank you! One can easily break the integral $$\int_{0}^{3}\frac{dx}{(x+j+1/2)\sqrt{x}} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(x+j+1/2)\sqrt{x}} + \int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{(x+j+1/2)\sqrt{x}} +\int_{2}^{3}\frac{dx}{(x+j+1/2)\sqrt{x}} $$ to get the desired relation which you pointed out.