# Prove or disprove $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{i+j+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i+\frac{1}{2}}}<\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{j+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

In [Example 2.3.5; Functional Analysis book by S. Kesavan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3267311/example-2-3-5-functional-analysis-book-by-s-kesavan/3268613?noredirect=1#comment6721534_3268613) it was shown that for $j\gt -\frac{1}{2}$

$$s(j) := \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{i+j+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i+\frac{1}{2}}}<\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{j+\frac{1}{2}}}\tag{1}$$

Numerically, even the stronger inequality seems to hold

$$s(j) <\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{j+1}}\tag{2}$$

I have proved $(1)$ by comparing the sum with an integral, but I didn't succeed to prove $(2)$. Can you find a proof?

Answer (score 0):

In S. Kesavan's example, we do no need the summation to begin from $i=0$. As $a_{ij}$ is not even defined there. Therefore, I was able to prove a relaxed version of the inequality.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(i+j+1)\sqrt{i+1/2}} = \frac{1}{(j+2)\sqrt{3/2}}+\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(i+j+1)\sqrt{i+1/2}} \tag{1}$$

Further,
$$\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(i+j+1)\sqrt{i+1/2}} < \sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(i+j+1)\sqrt{i}}<\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}(\int_{i-1}^{i}\frac{dx}{(x+j+1)\sqrt{x}})$$
$$\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}(\int_{i-1}^{i}\frac{dx}{(x+j+1)\sqrt{x}})=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+j+1)\sqrt{x}} \tag{2}$$

Also,
$$\frac{1}{(j+2)\sqrt{3/2}}<\frac{1}{(j+2)}<\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(x+j+1)\sqrt{x}} \tag{3}$$

From $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$ we have,
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(i+j+1)\sqrt{i+1/2}} < \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+j+1)\sqrt{x}} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{j+1}} $$

Comment: @ Himanshu Yadav  Notice that in the OP the sum starts at $i=0$. So you didn't provide the required proof.

Comment: @ Himanshu Yadav I have made a typo in the heading, which I have now corrected. However, from the context it should have been clear that it was $(2)$ which was to be proved.